# Facebook カタログマネージャ内のImageURLと広告への画像の反映について

Tags: facebook

先日、Imagelinkを変更せず、Imagelink内の画像だけを差し替えて入稿を行ったのですが、広告の画像が旧画像から変更されていないという事象がございました。
広告に反映されるのはDA Display Preview URLであり、ImageLinkの文字列に変更がない場合、ImageLinkの取り込みが行われないため、DA Display Preview URLも変更されないことまではわかりました。

しかし、画像変更の際にImageLinkを変更することが出来ないため、以下の方法でImageLinkを変更した場合、変更前のImageLinkと変更後のImageLinkは異なるものだと認識されますでしょうか。

例えば
 "image_link（Image）のURLにパラメータを割り当てる
（【商品画像URL】？Costom = "yymmdd"）
変更前：https://www.facebook.com/products/?Costom=20190520
変更後：https://www.facebook.com/products/?Costom=20190521

Comment: カタログとは何でしょうか？ ImageURLとは何でしょうか？ などなど。第三者に回答を求めたいのであれば、分かるように尋ねる必要があります。

Comment: 失礼いたしました。カタログはcatalogsのことで、 ImageLinkはImageLinkのこととなりますので以下修正いたします
先日、ImageLinkを変更せず、ImageLink内の画像だけ差し替えて入稿を行ったのですが
広告の画像が旧画像から変更されていないという事象がございました。
広告に反映されるのはDA Display Preview URLであり、
ImageLinkの文字列に変更がない場合、
ImageLinkの取り込みが行われないため、
DA Display Preview URLも変更されないことまではわかったのですが、
以下条件で商品画像を変更することは可能でしょうか。

・ImageLink（パラを除く）を変えない
・catalogs自体を変えない

Comment: Facebook カタログマネージャについての質問であることが分かったので、そのように質問文及びタイトルを変更しました。その上で、スタックオーバーフローよりもFacebookのサポートに問い合わせるべき内容であるように感じるため、クローズに投票致します。 [ここではどのようなトピックについて質問できますか? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Facebookサポートセンターでは解決しなかったのでお伺いしました。サポートセンター以外で本件についてお問い合わせ口がございましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです

Comment: Facebookサポートセンターに既に問い合わせているようですので、その問い合わせ内容とその返信をご記載ください。既に実施したけどうまく行かなかった事を書かないと、同じことを繰り返すだけになります。

Answer (score 0):

対象となる画像ファイルを削除されてはどうでしょうか。その後ブラウザのキャッシュを削除したうえで対象ページを表示してみてください。×アイコンが表示されるはずです。×アイコンの確認後、差し替えたい画像を適用してみてください。

Comment: 教えていただきありがとうございます。catalogsをアップロードするだけで画像が入れ替わる方法はないでしょうか。

Comment: 一般的なWebサイトの観点で回答してました。申し訳ありませんが、facebookに関しては知識がありません。生半可な知識ではありますがfacebook側の更新タイミングが遅延することがあるかどうかは気になります。スケジュール反映を行い、ご確認してはどうでしょうか。サポートセンターで解決しないということですのでアップロード条件を変えるなどしてテストを行うしかないかと思います。今まで正常に動作していたのであれば、異常動作する条件があるかもしれません。テストを行った結果を共有するとアドバイスをくれる方が出てくるかもしれません。